# How to get class name from a string?

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to detect class from a string.

example;

```
string test = "class Test { string Name; string PassWord;}"    
string[] classNames = GetClassNamesFromString(test);   
//Now string[0] has to be Test
```

Or more complex

```
string test = "[Export(typeof(ITest))]public class Test : ITest { }"    
string[] classNames = GetClassNamesFromString(test);   
//Now string[0] has to be Test
```

And must be work with generics.

Comment: Will your string always have this format? Or do you expect more complex strings like `namespace Foo { [TestClass] public class Bar { ... } }`?

Comment: `GetClassNamesFromString` should return a simple string `Test`?

Comment: It's very likely you're approaching the problem in the wrong way (that is, why are you parsing it like that?). Really, the solution can range from a simple regex "class ([a-Z0-9])" all the way up to implementing a parser and lexer for the grammer.

Comment: @user3325444 Then I'd advise you to look into something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/download.html) or you'll forever be tweaking your string parsing method .

Comment: @user3325444 What about `class Test<T>`?  What about `class foo:bar`?   What about `class quux{}`? what if there's a line break between `class` and the name?  Point being you are basically asking for someone to re-write a part of the lexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this way;

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

    var t = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
        using System;
        namespace Muhterem
        {
            class Main
            {   
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    Hello();
                }
                static void Hello()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }   
            class Generic<T>
            {}
            abstract class AbstractClass
            {}
        }
        ");

        var roo = t.GetRoot();
        var classes = roo.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
        foreach (var y in classes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(y.Identifier);
        }
```

and output ;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var input = "public class MyClass {//whatever}";    
var regex = new Regex(@"class\s(\w+)\s*[{,:]", RegexOptions.Compiled);  
var result = regex.Match(input);    
var className = result.Groups[1].Value;
```

If running this multiple times, use the `RegexOptions.Compiled` and store the `regex` in an instance variable to get better performance, otherwise you can remove the flag.

I let you take care of the error handling and don't forget to write some test conditions etc I have not added support for generics I also leave that to you to explore the awesomeness of REGEX.

Comment: Would fail on `class test{}`.

Comment: Good catch, fixed now.

Comment: I think `/s*` would be more appropriate (and `/s+` after class). Not meaning to pick on your answer, but it is not a trivial problem...

Answer (score 0):

I would simple use a Regex.

> class\s+(\w+\d*)+

In that maner:

```
string test = "[Export(typeof(ITest))]public class Test : ITest { }";
var match = Regex.Match(test, @"class\s+(\w+\d*)+");
string classname = match.Value.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

It even works with lots of space between class and the name:

```
string test = "[Export(typeof(ITest))]public class         Test : ITest { }";
```